# Facebook Reels Publishig API doesn't works

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the official [Reels Publishing Postman collection](https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/facebook/collection/23987686-f9afb0e6-c3fd-48a4-b48a-fde4bc574cf9) the reels get uploaded and published but only me can see the reel if I copy the reel link and share it, the people can't see the reel (I share the image), and my reels get 0 views

[image]

More data

- The video follows the guidelines
- I've tried it on different pages
- My token has the correct permissions
- The reels can get views but only when I watch the reels
- Like six months ago I tried use the API but it don't worked
- Oficial doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing

If someone needs more context I can give it

What I've tried?

- Use v15.0 and v17.0 (the latest at the moment)
- Schedule or not the reel doesn't work
- Search on the internet about this doesn't work, but I don't find anything related to my problem, thinking about it I find only fewer post, blogs, and topics related to using the API to upload reels

Comment: Most likely your app is still in development mode - as long as that is the case, any content created through it will only be visible to people with a role in the app. You will need to set your app live - and submit it for review, for any permissions/ features that might require such.