Why published reel is private after using Facebook with graph API and Python?
New reel does appear in fan page's Reels feed but it's invisible to users (i used another account to display the same feed and new reel is not there).
My "Page" perms:
publish_video
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts

Using this Python code to publish Facebook reel:
import os
import requests
from os.path import isfile
page_id= 'your business page id'
api_version= 'v20.0'
page_access_token= 'your_page_token'
def initialize_upload():
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{api_version}/{page_id}/video_reels"
    payload = {
        'upload_phase': 'start',
        'access_token': page_access_token
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    json = r.json()
    if r.status_code == 200:
        video_id = r.json()['video_id']
    else:
        raise Exception(json) 
    return video_id

def process_upload( video_id, file_size, file_data):

 
    url = f'https://rupload.facebook.com/video-upload/{api_version}/{video_id}'
    payload = {
        'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + page_access_token,
        'offset': '0',
        'file_size': str(file_size),
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=file_data, headers=payload)
    json = r.json()
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(json)

def publish( video_id, description, publish_time=None):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{api_version}/{page_id}/video_reels"

    payload = {
        'access_token': page_access_token,
        'video_id': video_id,
        'upload_phase': 'finish',
        'description': description,
    }
    if publish_time:
        payload['video_state'] = 'SCHEDULED'
        payload['scheduled_publish_time'] = publish_time
    else:
        payload['video_state'] = 'PUBLISHED'

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    json = r.json()
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(json)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_id = initialize_upload()
    print(video_id)
    
    mp4_path= r"C:\test\Facebook.mp4"

        
    if isfile(mp4_path):
        file_size = os.path.getsize(mp4_path)
        file_data= open(mp4_path, 'rb')
        process_upload(video_id, file_size, file_data)
        publish(video_id,  '#description')
    else:
        print('File not found')

Metadata (those views are mine):
{'comments': {'data': [],
              'summary': {'can_comment': True,
                          'order': 'chronological',
                          'total_count': 0}},
 'created_time': '2024-08-13T16:22:02+0000',
 'description': '#test',
 'from': {'id': '***', 'name': 'Test'},
 'id': '***',
 'is_crossposting_eligible': True,
 'likes': {'data': [],
           'summary': {'can_like': True, 'has_liked': False, 'total_count': 0}},
 'permalink_url': '/reel/***/',
 'privacy': {'allow': '',
             'deny': '',
             'description': 'Public',
             'friends': '',
             'networks': '',
             'value': 'EVERYONE'},
 'status': {'copyright_check_status': {'matches_found': False,
                                       'status': 'complete'},
            'processing_phase': {'status': 'complete'},
            'publishing_phase': {'publish_status': 'published',
                                 'publish_time': '2024-08-13T17:33:12+0000',
                                 'status': 'complete'},
            'uploading_phase': {'bytes_transferred': 13671054,
                                'status': 'complete'},
            'video_status': 'ready'},
 'views': 45}

Any idea why is it private?

Your app is still in development mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984265/facebook-reels-publishig-api-doesnt-works

The problem was missing permission.
Here are Page perms you need to create public reel:
publish_video
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
public_profile

